# How does gravitational potential energy increase, if field decreases as $h$ increases?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, potential-energy

(In the following constants are ommitted)

1. Let $ M = 50, m = 5, h = 5$. Then
   $$ \text{Potential Energy} = \frac{50\cdot5}{5} = 50.$$

While after increasing the height $h$:

2. $ M = 50 , m =5, h =10 $, and
   $$\text{Potential Energy} = \frac{50\cdot5}{10} = 25.$$

Field strength decreases amount of $h^2$ so according to formulas potential energy decreases as $h$ increases.

But that cannot be true. But as I showed according to Potential energy and Field strength formulas, potential energy decreases as $h$ increases. What is wrong here?

Comment: Note that the thing you are calling "gravitational potential energy" it better called "*change* in gravitational potential energy between two places". Then think about the problem a little more.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot that gravitational potential energy is *negative* (it is defined as zero when the objects are infinitely far apart). Add a minus sign to your calculations, and you're good.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that, in physics, conservative fields are related to potentials by the relation
$$\mathbf F = -\nabla U.$$
This is because the work done by the field is converted into potential energy and vice-versa through the consevation
$$\Delta U + W = 0,$$
where
$$W = \int_\gamma \mathbf F\cdot\mathbf v\ \text dt$$
is the work along the path $\gamma$, and $\Delta U$ is the variation of potential energy between the end-points of $\gamma$.